# SVG onclick lower object to bottom

Tags: svg

I've created `SVG` images with `Inkscape` that are embedded in a `SharePoint` Wiki page. I regularly use these two attributes within `Inkscape` (Object Properties -> Interactivity):

```
onmouseover: this.style.opacity=0

onmouseout: this.style.opacity=1
```

This allows to hide the object on top in order to reveal another object I placed behind.

Using the `onclick` attribute, is there a way to lower the object on top to the background? Something like `onclick: this.object.lower...`

Comment: You'd have to move the element to be earlier in the file than the elements that cover it.

Answer (score 0):

By lower do you mean moving it's position on the page? Or changing what layer of the page the image shows on? Given the OnMouseOver example I'm guessing the latter. You don't need to use onclick for this at all. Set the SVG image that's supposed to be 'behind' as the background of the parent div. Then set the forefront one with a background-color and background-image:url('path/to/my.svg').

```
<style>
.backgroundImage, .foregroundImage {height:5em;width:5em;}
.backgroundImage {background:url('../img/logo.png') #fff center center no-repeat; background-size:4em 4em;}
.foregroundImage {background:url('../img/logo.png') red center center no-repeat; background-size:1em 1em;}
.foregroundImage:hover {background:none;}
</style>
<div class="backgroundImage"><div class="foregroundImage"></div></div>
```

You can see an example of exactly how to do this here in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9yyfjh3/) -I didn't have any handy images so I just used their logo for the background URL's

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I need to perform such an action within Inkscape since SharePoint 2013 does not understand SVG: I have to insert the SVG code in a Script Editor Webpart.

Comment: SharePoint 2013 supports SVG just fine, save the SVG to a .svg file and reference it like an image.